# Is it possible to run specific Babel (6) Plugins before Eslint (2.0) runs when using with Webpack?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, eslint

The title pretty much covers my issue but what I'm basically wanting is

1. Specific babel plugin runs to convert my es6 import statements to the appropriate paths
2. Eslint runs telling me if there are issues with my code, which includes if there are any paths that are unresolvable
3. The rest of babel gets run converting my code from es6 to es5
4. Complete

Is this feasible?

**Update**

I'm using https://github.com/michaelzoidl/babel-root-import

`//.babelrc
{
  ...,
  "plugins": [["babel-root-import", {
    "rootPathSuffix": "./src"
  }]],
  ...
}`

And in my webpack config I have a babel loader and an eslint loader like so

`//webpack.config.dev.js
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel', 'eslint'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    ...
}`

After this I can then import modules using a syntax like

`import Module from '~/components/Module'`

rather than

`import Module from '../../components/Module`

Answer (score 1):

ESLint validates files "as is" right from the file system without any extra preprocessing. For your case, you can create custom eslint rule, that understands your processed paths and can check them.

As other option, you can call Babel with your path processor the only plugin enabled, check the result with eslint and then run babel again with rest of plugins to convert the code to es5. But for me, the first way seems easier and nicer.

P.S. Maybe I can add something if you tell what the your path converting actually is.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, yea sorry I didn't give a ton of information, I'll update my question

Comment: I think the best option here is asking eslint plugin author to add this feature for you. Which one plugin are you using for checking imports?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was using https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import

Comment: You can probably file an issue in that project with your request and link that question as the original source